# Own Android Theme doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, styles, themes

I have a problem with creating my own theme. In Eclipse the project looks fine, it even looks as it should in Graphical Layout preview, when I open my .xml with layout. I've tried on several devices with Android, also with virtual. The effect is the same, the app looks like it is using the default Theme.

I have my own layout defined in styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <style name="OwnTheme1" parent="AppBaseTheme">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in my AndroidManifest.xml file it looks like the following:

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/OwnTheme1">
```

Do I need anything else to make it work? I'm running it on the newest Android KitKat version.

Comment: What is it that is not showing as expected?